# How to use regex with terraform data source filters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a terraform data source which looks as below:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "all_region_az" {
  all_availability_zones = true
  state = "available"
  filter {
    name = "names"
    values = [regex("us-east-1[a-z]")]
  }
}
```

I want to add a regex here so that only the availability zones ending with a single alphabetic char are filtered out.

My default region is `us-east-1.`

Examples:

- us-east-1a
- us-east-1b
- us-east-1c
- us-east-1d
- us-east-1e

Comment: Using a regex in the filter is not going to work because the filter expects the list of regions to filter on. You are better of retrieving all the zones, and then using locals for loop to filter the data.
```data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {
  state = "available"
}
locals {
  az_names = [for name in data.a ws_availability_zones.azs.names:  name if regexall("us-east-1[a-z]", name) > 0
]```

Comment: The AWS APi does not allow this in the request: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeAvailabilityZones.html. You would need to use the `regex` to process the response in the data attributes. We need to see its usage in your config to assist further.